# Swift upload image status code 200 error

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, image-uploading

Hello i have image upload codes looking good but gives status 200 error code and dont upload image to server my codes here.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageUploadProgressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var uploadButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

        self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        myImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        uploadImage()

    }




    func uploadImage()
    {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)

        if(imageData == nil ) { return }

        self.uploadButton.enabled = false

        let uploadScriptUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.bla.com/upload.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: uploadScriptUrl!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")

        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

        let task = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: imageData!)
        task.resume()

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?)
    {
        print("didCompleteWithError")

        let myAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
        myAlert.show()

        self.uploadButton.enabled = true

    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64)
    {
        print("didSendBodyData")
        let uploadProgress:Float = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)

        imageUploadProgressView.progress = uploadProgress
        let progressPercent = Int(uploadProgress*100)
        progressLabel.text = "\(progressPercent)%"
        print(uploadProgress)
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void)
    {
        print("didReceiveResponse")
        print(response);
        self.uploadButton.enabled = true
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData)
    {
        print("didReceiveData")
          print(data);
    }

}
```

My upload.php

```
<?

$target_dir = "upload";

if(!file_exists($target_dir))
{
mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}

$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
echo json_encode([
"Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
"Status" => "OK"
]);

} else {

echo json_encode([
"Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
"Status" => "Error"
]);
}

?>
```

Xcode upload progress later gives response error here;

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fbbd171bac0> { URL: http://www.bla.com/upload.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Wed, 03 Feb 2016 12:36:18 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = Apache;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.17";
} }
```

Thanks for your help. im trying everything but i didnt resolve it.

Thank you !

Comment: status code: 200 is success not error

Comment: @HamzaAnsari but dont upload image.

Comment: 200 only is returned by the server if the connection was successful, which in this case it was. What you should be looking for is the response JSON to see which part of your code executed based on the JSON you get back

Comment: Where did you put your request body? You need to add your image data to the parameter that you send to your API.